YAML recipe does not work if YAML files are located in root project folder
Issue:
When using OpenRewrite API, YAML recipes do not work if the .yaml files are located in the root directory of the project. However, if the .yaml files are placed in a subdirectory of the project, the YAML recipes work as expected.
Directory Structure:
project-root-directory
│
├── .yaml files (YAML recipes do not work)
│
├── subdirectory
│   ├── .yaml files (YAML recipes work)
│
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   ├── resources
│   ├── test
│
├── pom.xml

In the above directory structure, the YAML recipes do not work for the .yaml files located directly under the project-root-directory. However, if the .yaml files are located under a subdirectory within the project-root-directory, the YAML recipes work as expected.
I have tested with DeleteKey and MergeYaml recipes. I have to change in couples of project where YAML files are located in root directory of project.

Could you explain a bit more about how you're running OpenRewrite? "When using OpenRewrite API" is a bit vague to me. There should be no such limitations, as we do parse additional resources unless explicitly disabled: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/blob/ff336f0a1b7233705dc167d192c081bc02978e65/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/maven/MavenMojoProjectParser.java#L201-L205

I got the issue after running in debug mode, Issue is with parsing the YAML:-
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1199 out of bounds for length 1025
at org.openrewrite.yaml.YamlParser.shouldUseYamlParserBugWorkaround (YamlParser.java:387) at org.openrewrite.yaml.YamlParser.parseFromInput (YamlParser.java:338) at org.openrewrite.yaml.YamlParser.lambda$parseInputs$0 (YamlParser.java:70)
[WARNING] There were problems parsing codeway-development.yaml
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1199 out of bounds for length 1025..Is there any limitation of Char value in YAML?

Ah yes that's an issue that's been solved in the latest snapshots. I'll do a release tomorrow to flush that out. Until then you can use the snapshot versions.

what would be the fixed version number.

The fixed versions are listed here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-recipe-bom/releases/tag/v2.12.0
We'll update the docs tomorrow

This was an issue since fixed in openrewrite/rewrite/commit/977b8e497036fe5521dac8e891a0eb70e05b0861
Use rewrite-recipe-bom v2.12.0 and the associated plugin versions going forward.
